# Command to delete full sentences or dictation session?

Tags: voice-recognition, voice-command, delete, google-voice-actions

Is there a way to delete entire sentences when using voice recognition? Perhaps the functionality I am asking about doesn't even exists?

Comment: Umm, there's no Google employees on this site, so you're on the wrong site if you suggest us to upvote this to let Google know (no, it doesn't work like that). However, little research proved that there's no "delete" voice command; you have to press the "delete" button on the screen. Unfortunately, I can't find [product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!home) for Google Keyboard (which includes voice typing). You might try to post this on [AOSP issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) as "Enhancement" instead. (However, we can't ensure it)

Comment: edit made, don't take it too seriously.. I doubt "Voice dictation" is pretty high on their list of things to worry about.  But note taken.

Comment: That's okay, I understand that this is an actual problem for users who always use this feature instead of typing. Hopefully this gets answers for alternatives/workarounds (I think you need to use different voice dictation app), but I'm not particular experienced in this area.

Comment: Hey, it was a good idea!  I filed them with AOSP!  If you wouldn't have mentioned it, it probably never wouldn't have bothered to get done!
174573 Defect New ----   User confirmation to keep buffer after Voice Detection Session ends 1  
Vote for this issue and get email change notifications 174572 Defect New ----   Sentence Deletion in Voice Detection Session.